# Ubuntu 22.04: Periodic loss of video, fans come on full, requires restart

Tags: graphics, 22.04, crash

I have just completed a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a new PC.

Everything works but a couple of times a day, the screen will go blank whilst I am using the machine (different applications, no pattern).  My fans then come on full and the monitor says there is no signal on the HDMI connection.

The system still seems to be running at this point as the music I listen to through the web browser continues to play.  The only way I can resolve the situation is to do a hard reset of the machine.

I thought it was an issue with the Nvidia 515 proprietary driver that I installed to drive my Nvidia RTX 3060 graphics card but I have tried using Nouveau instead and the issue still exists.  I have also tried downgrading to Nvidia driver 470 but that made no difference.  I have also tried using X11 and Wayland, and both suffer the same crash.

I am not well versed in debugging techniques for things like this.  How should I go about finding out what the problem is?  I looked at the output of dmesg after reboot but didn't find anything obviously relevant.

The configuration of my system is:

Intel® Core™ i9 16-Core Processor i9-12900K (3.2GHz) 30MB Cache

ASUS® TUF GAMING Z690-PLUS WIFI D4 (LGA1700, USB 3.2, PCIe 5.0)

128GB Corsair VENGEANCE DDR4 3000MHz (4 x 32GB)

2x 2TB SAMSUNG 970 EVO PLUS M.2, PCIe NVMe

12GB NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3060 - HDMI, DP, LHR

Comment: Oh?  Interesting...because I've been having the same problem.  It was happening about twice a day for me.  Literally, just yesterday, I looked around and one thing I'm now trying is another display manager (`lightdm`) and desktop environment (previously was `ubuntu`; now, I'm using `gnome`).  So far, today has been ok...but I think I'd try it a few more days before I think I am done.  It's happening on two installations of Ubuntu 22.04 for me...  Anyway, if you give this a try, it would be good if you follow-up so that we can compare notes...  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the [GPU is overheating and shutting itself down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWELCn-SvGY) to prevent damage.

The video linked in question solved the problem by repasting the board. You may notice the sensors didn't indicate the GPU was overheating, yet it was.

However if the GPU is still under warranty you should ask for an RMA rather than attempting to repaste it yourself.

Or your [PSU is not powerful enough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnRyyCsuHFQ) for your card (a common problem this 3000 generation because the 'transient peaks' are ***far*** above the average power draw but they last for so little that most sensors won't even register it, yet it's powerful enough to cause malfunctions or trip protections).

If transient peaks are the problem, there may be solutions this [comment says](https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabytegaming/comments/mkqumm/comment/hs4pe71/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> For anyone else still having this problem....I just fixed it for myself by going into my motherboard bios and setting the PCI slot from auto, to Gen 3. Nothing else worked.

That actually makes sense, since having the GPU forced to stay at a fixed power draw (even if it's higher power draw in average) helps stabilizing it, which means the gap in the peaks aren't that large. Thus you may be able to fix the problem by configuring stuff that affects dynamic power saving.

I suggest trying to see if the problem replicates on Windows under load. If the problem persists on Windows, then it's bad HW. The GeForce 30XX series going black and ramping up the fans [is a](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/470574/blackscreen-and-gpu-fans-go-full-speed-rtx-3060/?topicPage=10) [common](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgamingtechsupport/comments/rbcpz1/black_screen_gpu_fans_ramp_up_to_100/) [HW](https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabytegaming/comments/occp37/sudden_black_screen_and_gpu_fans_ramps_up_to_100/) [problem](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/fans-speed-up-and-screen-goes-black-requires-restart.3750238/).